How to get current page URL in next-auth google provider
I am new to next-auth, I am trying to make scopes dynamic and for that I need to get current page URL inside fetchScopes code.
Below is my code in [...nextauth]/route.js

let cachedScopes = [];
let loginscopes = [
    "openid",
    "email",
    "profile",
]; 
let scopes =[];
const fetchScopes = async (from) => {

    console.log('Page from query:', from);

    if (from == 'access') {
        try {
            const fetchedScopes = await fetchScopesUsingSlug(from);
            if (fetchedScopes && fetchedScopes.google) {
                cachedScopes = fetchedScopes.google || [];
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching additional scopes:", error);
        }
    }else{
        loginscopes = []
    }

    scopes = [...loginscopes, ...cachedScopes];

};

Below is my code for providers:
providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorization: {
            url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
            params: {
                redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google",
                scope: [
                    ...scopes
                    
                ].join(" "),
                response_type: "code",
            },
        },
         checks: ['none'],
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
        clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorization: {
            params: {
                scope: "email public_profile pages_manage_posts pages_manage_engagement pages_show_list ads_management business_management catalog_management ads_management leads_retrieval read_insights instagram_basic pages_show_list instagram_manage_insights"
            },
        },
    }),
    
],

Inside fetchScopes function, I want to get current page URL, do anyone have any idea how it can be done?
I had tried several ways, but nothing worked, I tried to make authorization a async function and then I added a console in it, but that didn't got triggered.

Where in code you are calling fetchScopes function ??
